# Dynamic html fragments with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, pdf-generation, reporting, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to load html fragments and show inside div tag. So I wrote a simple directive:

```
myDirectives.directive('myRpt', function () {
    'use strict';
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            var htmlExpr = attrs.myRpt;
            scope.$watch(htmlExpr, function (newHtml) {
                if (newHtml) {
                    elem.html(newHtml);
                }
            }, false);
        }
    };
});
```

In html page it is used like below:

```
<div my-rpt="report">
</div>
```

Now in a controller I have:

```
$http.get('api/v1/general_ledger', { params: { q: { filter: [
    { 'name': 'begin_date', 'op': '==', 'val': $scope.criteria.beginDate },
    { 'name': 'end_date', 'op': '==', 'val': $scope.criteria.endDate }]
}}}).then(
    function (resp) {
        $scope.report = resp.data;
    },
    function (resp) {
        //TODO: show error message
    }
);
```

The above code works, but I'm not sure whether it is good enough approach. For example, $scope.report may hold very big string/html content, but I guess browser will have its own parsed copy. Also, in general what are the good ways to author business reports, and when required, to generate pdf, excel files etc.?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create your own directive, since you can use

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtml

or

http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtmlUnsafe

Answer (score 0):

Since the element content is plain, server-generated HTML without dynamic bindings, I don't see why not using this approach.

If the HTML string is big enough, you can use it and then delete it so as not to consume memory. Deleting it would probably require slightly different code, e.g. using events and specifying the event name as an attribute to the directive:

```
// in the controller:
$http.get(...).then(
    function(resp) {
        $rootScope.broadcast("receivedReport", resp.data);
    },
...

// in the directive:
link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
    var eventName = attrs.myRpt;
    scope.$on(eventName, function(data) {
        elem.html(data);
    });
}
```

Template usage:

```
<div my-rpt="receivedReport"></div>
```